# How can I acess my data child from v-if in vue?

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm trying to acess another variable from a for in vue, but I can't acess this...

```html
<div class="list-group" v-for="index in max_slots">
    <div v-if="user[index].firstname">
        <a href="#">{{user[index].firstname}} {{user[index].lastname}}</a>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <a href="#">Empty Slot</a>
    </div>   
</div>
```

and the data is like that:

```js
data(){
        return{
            max_slots: 5,
            user: [
                {
                    firstname: 'Max',
                    lastname: 'Trox'
                },
                {
                    firstname: 'Alexandra',
                    lastname: 'Rhae'
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

It's always show me 'Empty Slot' or not even load the page

Answer (score 1):

My solution is by adding condition in `v-if` to read if the data `user[index]` is not `undefined`, here I how would do it:

```
<div class="list-group" v-for="index in max_slots">
    <div v-if="user[index-1]">
        <a href="#">{{user[index-1].firstname}} {{user[index-1].lastname}}</a>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <a href="#">Empty Slot</a>
    </div>   
</div>
```

I changed `v-if="user[index].firstname"` to `v-if="user[index-1]"`. The logic behind this is that it will render the item in `user` when they are not undefined. Also, you have to substract the `index` by `-1` because `v-for="index in max_slots"` will count from `1, 2, ...max_slots` and not fom `0` while array count start from `0`, or it makes the first data in `user` to be ignored.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      max_slots: 5,
      user: [{
          firstname: 'Max',
          lastname: 'Trox'
        },
        {
          firstname: 'Alexandra',
          lastname: 'Rhae'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="list-group" v-for="index in max_slots">
    <div v-if="user[index-1]">
      <a href="#">{{user[index-1].firstname}} {{user[index-1].lastname}}</a>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <a href="#">Empty Slot</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `v-if` condition is throwing an error when `index` is out of bound for users. Changing it to `user[index]` or `v-if="index < user.length"` should work.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      max_slots: 5,
      user: [
        {
          firstname: 'Max',
          lastname: 'Trox'
        },
        {
          firstname: 'Alexandra',
          lastname: 'Rhae'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <div class="list-group" v-for="index in max_slots">
    <div v-if="user[index]">
      <a href="#">{{user[index].firstname}} {{user[index].lastname}}</a>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <a href="#">Empty Slot</a>
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```